# Autoplay GIFs when on screen and stop on scrolling

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gif

How to autoplay Gifs when they apper on screen and stop on scroll away in my React web application. Help me!
I have tried this.

```
<GifPlayer
 gif={url}
 pauseRef={pause => this.pauseGif = pause}/>
```

This is not working as on clicking on the gif I have to navigate to another screen. So if there is a way that the Gif plays automatically when it appears on the screen and stops on scrolling away then it would work smoothly.

Comment: It would help if you showed what you've tried and explained what you're trying to do. Remember, we're here to help you code, not code for you

Comment: I have added what I have tried.

Comment: Maybe use state to swap the gif with a still image that matches the begining of the gif? It wouldnt pause the gif techically but you could control when the gif starts and stops. You could use scrollTop or mouseEnter events.